# Why does iCloud Drive get stuck?

Tags: icloud, macos

Uploading of Desktop and Documents to iCloud hasn't worked for me for months (macOS 10.12).

I have now started from scratch with a brand-new install, and am trying to sync just ~70MB of files that are sitting on the desktop.

It's been stuck on "77.8MB of 77.8MB" for 3 days.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

I've looked at possible solutions (like logging out etc.), but this is a fresh install, shouldn't it just work?

Comment: Other questions of this, ordered by number of votes:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/264915/63255,
https://superuser.com/q/1045791/203848,
https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/313716/63255.
Most successful resolutions seems to be `killall bird`, and if necessary first deleting `${HOME}/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All programs are supposed to “just work”, however bugs are unavoidable when humans are programming.

With a brand new install it seems that logging out or rebooting the Mac to test if this fixes the problem shouldn't be a problem. So you might want to give that a try.

If you want to fix the problem without logging out or rebooting, try opening a terminal and running:

```
brctl log -w --shorten
```

This should give you a reasonably readable output of log info from the syncing process. Hopefully this will give you a clue as to why the process isn't progressing.

You can also try simply killing the `bird` process that handles the synchronization. When it starts again it might progress to completion.

Comment: Killing the bird processes (two in my case) from Activity Monitor worked for me. Finder showed an alert about the stuck download failing, but after double-clicking in the file again it downloaded in a breeze.

Comment: On macOS Catalina 10.15.3, the command does not work as described. Use ```brctl log -w --shorten``` instead.

Comment: I have tried your method. It re-indicised and re-synchronised all iCloud, but, at the end, the same 40 files are being synced.

Answer (score 3):

for exactly the same problem, raising Bird priority fixed the problem instantly.
see [iCloud Drive is stuck uploading items and no longer syncs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264915/icloud-drive-is-stuck-uploading-items-and-no-longer-syncs)

no other solution was working before (killing Bird, removing CloudDocs)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/312547)