# iCloud not uploading files (Monterey, M1)

Tags: icloud, monterey

Every time I add a new file to iCloud from my MacBook Pro M1 (2021, Monterey 12.2.1), it does not upload. Instead, I just get a hollow cloud and an "uploading" icon indefinitely:

[image: Uploading document]

The status bar tells me that the file is uploading (and there is plenty of space), but remains stuck at Zero KB:

[image: Status bar]

I have tried:

- rebooting
- `touch`ing the files to attempt to force refresh
- signing in and out of iCloud

The only thing I have found that works is quitting the `bird` process, often multiple times to get a single file to upload. (For instance, to upload the 6.6MB file from the screenshot, I had to kill `bird` twice.)

I would sure like to know how to get iCloud to work as it is a major part of my workflow!

Comment: How long are you waiting for the file to be uploaded to iCloud?  I don't think it does these uploads instantly, it could take some time depending on what's happening on your device.

Comment: Tens of minutes if not hours. Prior to getting a new computer and upgrading the OS, uploads always happened directly after creating files. Uploads in other file syncing platforms like Dropbox and Google Drive happen immediately.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/434258/88313) help?  There's many questions on this site related to iCloud upload problems so be sure to search and see if any of those answers help resolve it.

Comment: I did search before posting, and came across that answer. But on your suggestion I reread it now. The first time I was distracted by the first few suggestions, which don't apply to me. But just now I was able to solve my issue based on the last portion of the answer. Now I'm not sure whether it's better to delete this question, or to answer it myself.

Comment: If the issue is the same and solution that was there helped you then this question should be closed as a duplicate of that one.  If it's a different problem then add the solution and a link to that post as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I think this question can be closed as duplicate but I don't have sufficient reputation to do so. Feel free to do so.