# Cannot copy folder in "Documents and Desktop" folders linked with iCloud Drive

Tags: macos, icloud, finder, command-line

I am using a MacBook Air (M1, 2020) with macOS Monterey Version 12.5 (21G72). I recall nothing unusual until yesterday when I tried to duplicate or copy one folder on my Desktop folder. The process seems to always be stuck at

```
 Zero bytes of 2 KB - Estimating time remaining ...
```

[image: Screenshot of Finder dialog box showing a copy process]

or often the process failed and I received this:

[image: Screenshot of Finder dialog box showing error message]

Now, this is a list of what I have tried so far:

### What does not work

1. Because my `Desktop` and `Documents` folders are synced with iCloud Drive, I tried copying/duplicating folders in Documents and the result is the same as above.
2. I tried to do a `killall bird` in Terminal as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441555/231349).
3. I tried the process described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391917/231349).
4. I tried resetting SMC and rebooting my Mac.
5. I tried disabling iCloud Drive and then re-enable it.
6. Copy/duplicate of folder won't work regardless of size.

### What does work

1. I tried copying/duplicating the folder with `cp` in Terminal, and it works perfectly.
2. I tried copying/duplicating the folder in `~/Downloads` with Finder, and it works perfectly.
3. Copy/duplicate of files works regardless of size.

I hope this frustration will not occur to any of you.

Is there an option to let finder copy items or do I need to host these files outside iCloud Drive if I need to copy them?

Comment: Same problem, no solution for the moment.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I tried everything, including the approaches you listed in your post... Will keep monitoring this post, hopefully someone has a solution. This is extremely annoying

Answer (score -1):

Try right-clicking on the folder or find whatever data doesn't have read/write permissions, click **Get Info**, and at the bottom is **Sharing & Permissions**. If you find a file that you don't have those permissions on, change it there and try again.

Comment: This doesn't work, have tried this as well.