# Does the bird daemon log anywhere // troubleshooting stuck iCloud sync

Tags: iphone, icloud

Is there a way to enable iCloud Sync telemetry/logging?

Something is getting stuck uploading to iCloud but I can't tell what it is. [Popular suggestion is to kill -9 bird](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264915/icloud-drive-is-stuck-uploading-items-and-no-longer-syncs) but that is not working for me.

1. Nothing obvious is showing up in Console.app.
2. Running bird is not helpful either:

```
>  ./bird -h
Usage: bird [options]

    -h,--help            show this help
```

3. LaunchAgent `com.apple.bird.plist` is not very interesting either, though it does point to the sync directory:

```
<key>com.apple.bird.fsevents</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>Path</key>
                                <string>~/Library/Mobile Documents</string>
                        </dict>
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: iCloud logging is already enabled. You are gong to need to look a bit harder with Console app. Start by searching for `bird` or `cloudd`.  I am not suggesting this is the easy solution - just that it is the only way.

Comment: @Gilby I see both `bird` and `cloudd` in the logs, but there's nothing of use here. I was wondering if there's a way to increase verbosity.

Comment: Maybe the answer you're looking for is to view 'open files and ports' tab for the process in Activity Monitor?  For me, bird was going nuts and I didn't care to further troubleshoot it, as I expect it to resolve with the next reboot, and I used `killall -sigstop bird` to 'solve' the problem 'till then, as I don't need iCloud docs and don't want it downloading tons of stuff unnecessarily.  A right click on iCloud shows it's downloading 18GB I don't want it to.